Text outside of the cell
How can i fix the issue shown in this image, the text 'Controler' spawns outside the cell.

Here is my code :
  \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}[H]
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tablists}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float,lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[ Lenny]{fncychap}
\graphicspath{{Logos/}}

% Redefine the names of lists
\addto\captionsfrench{%
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}%
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Liste des tableaux}%
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
    \begin{tabular}{
            !{\vrule width 1pt}m{2cm}<{\centering}!{\vrule width 1pt}
            p{5cm}!{\vrule width 1pt}
            p{5cm}!{\vrule width 1pt}
            p{2.5cm}!{\vrule width 1pt}}
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
        \rowcolor{gray!25}
        \textbf{Phases} & \textbf{Objectifs/taches} & \textbf{Résultats} & \textbf{Outils principaux} \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
        \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Définir}} 
        & Établissement des objectifs et des limites du projet. Identification des questions clés pour atteindre l'efficacité maximale.
        & Identifier les parties prenantes impliquées. Préciser les données d'entrée et de sortie.
        & QQQQCP \newline SIPOC \newline SWOT \newline 6-packs \newline GIMSI \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
        \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Mesurer}} 
        & Examiner la situation actuelle en collectant les données pertinentes sur les problèmes abordés.
        & Repérer les éléments impliqués dans la problématique.
        & Chronométrages \newline VSM \newline Pareto \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
        \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Analyser}} 
        & Identifier les causes fondamentales des problèmes évaluées précédemment.
        & Aquérir une compréhension approfondie des causes principales des anomalies.
        & Ishikawa \newline Brainstorming \newline 5 Pourquoi \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
        \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Innover}} 
        & Explorer et recommander des solutions pour résoudre le problème.
        & Réduire les causes sous-jacentes du problème.
        & Brainstorming \newline Matrice Cause/Amélior- \newline ation \newline Plan d'action \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
        \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Contrôler}\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{6ex}} 
        & Surveiller l'avancement de la solution modifiée.
        & Étudier les écarts.
        & Bilan des gains. \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Démarche DMAIC}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}

Thanks in advance.

Welcome! Please make your code complilable.

The last \multirow{5}{*} seems meaningless. Why do you use it?

I used it to make each of 'Outils Principaux' elements in its own cell, but it didnt work.

how can I make the code complilable ?

"Compilable" means that you start your code with \documentclass and end it with \end{document}. Include all necessary packages, but not more, to make your issue reproducable. It is unclear to me, why you use \multirow at all in your table.

I modified the code as wanted sir.

Your code has way too many packages for this specific example, and the compilation gives an error.
However, the problem in the table can be solved by changing some of the \multirows. \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Mesurer}}, \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Analyser}}, \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Contrôler}.

Thank you for your help.

Doesn't seem minimal. Anyway, welcome TeX.se @SpikeSp

A bit simpler with tabularray.
BTW, don't confuse "tache" and "tâche" ;)
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={@{}c*{3}{X[c,m]}@{}},
        column{1}={font=\bfseries, gray!10},
        row{1}={font=\bfseries, gray!25},
      }
      \toprule
      Phases & Objectifs/tâches & Résultats & Outils principaux \\
      \midrule
      Définir 
      & Établissement des objectifs et des limites du projet. Identification des questions clés pour atteindre l'efficacité maximale.
      & Identifier les parties prenantes impliquées. Préciser les données d'entrée et de sortie.
      & QQQQCP \par SIPOC \par SWOT \par 6-packs \par GIMSI \\
      \midrule
      Mesurer 
      & Examiner la situation actuelle en collectant les données pertinentes sur les problèmes abordés.
      & Repérer les éléments impliqués dans la problématique.
      & Chronométrages \par VSM \par Pareto \\
      \midrule
      Analyser
      & Identifier les causes fondamentales des problèmes évaluées précédemment.
      & Aquérir une compréhension approfondie des causes principales des anomalies.
      & Ishikawa \par Brainstorming \par 5 Pourquoi \\
      \midrule
      Innover
      & Explorer et recommander des solutions pour résoudre le problème.
      & Réduire les causes sous-jacentes du problème.
      & Brainstorming \par Matrice Cause/Amélioration \par Plan d'action \\
      \midrule
      Contrôler
      & Surveiller l'avancement de la solution modifiée.
      & Étudier les écarts.
      & Bilan des gains. \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Démarche DMAIC}
  \end{table}
  
\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{>{\columncolor{mygray}\bfseries}l*{3}{X[c,m]}@{}}
      \toprule
      \RowStyle[rowcolor=mygray]{\bfseries}
      Phases & Objectifs/tâches & Résultats & Outils principaux \\
      \midrule
      Définir 
      & Établissement des objectifs et des limites du projet. Identification des questions clés pour atteindre l'efficacité maximale.
      & Identifier les parties prenantes impliquées. Préciser les données d'entrée et de sortie.
      & QQQQCP \par SIPOC \par SWOT \par 6-packs \par GIMSI \\
      \midrule
      Mesurer 
      & Examiner la situation actuelle en collectant les données pertinentes sur les problèmes abordés.
      & Repérer les éléments impliqués dans la problématique.
      & Chronométrages \par VSM \par Pareto \\
      \midrule
      Analyser
      & Identifier les causes fondamentales des problèmes évaluées précédemment.
      & Aquérir une compréhension approfondie des causes principales des anomalies.
      & Ishikawa \par Brainstorming \par 5 Pourquoi \\
      \midrule
      Innover
      & Explorer et recommander des solutions pour résoudre le problème.
      & Réduire les causes sous-jacentes du problème.
      & Brainstorming \par Matrice Cause/Amélioration \par Plan d'action \\
      \midrule
      Contrôler
      & Surveiller l'avancement de la solution modifiée.
      & Étudier les écarts.
      & Bilan des gains. \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Démarche DMAIC}
  \end{table}
  
\end{document}


